# Synchronizing the database failed with the message 'string truncation...'

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, compact-database

Using N-Tier synchronization to a Microsoft Compact DB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882690.aspx. Trying to refresh the local database cache to account for changes in the schema of the db we are syncing against.

In the middle of Synchronizing local database cache, the message Synchronizing the database failed with the message 'String truncation: max=100, len=101,value='...'.' appears.

The column it complains about is actually nvarchar(400), so might just need to delete and add the local database cache again, but wanted to record it somewhere just in case it is useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recreating the local database cache fixed the problem.